# Can PHP CLI be made to receive signals during readline()?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, signals

I'm working on a small Linux console app that starts with a Q&A implemented using PHP's `readline()` function. I want the user to be able to quit the app with the standard `Ctrl+C` / `SIGINT` and have their input saved to resume later. I'm using php-cli-7.2.

Here are the relevant parts of the code in abstract:

```
pcntl_async_signals(true);
pcntl_signal(SIGINT,function($sigNo,$sigInfo=null) {
    saveWork();
    exit(0);
});

$questions = ['How','Why','Where'];
$answers = [];
foreach($questions as $k => $v) {
    $answers[] = readline("$v? ");
}
```

The problem is that during the `readline()` call, php-cli will not respond to this signal, whether typed on the active terminal or sent via another, until after the user hits Enter.

This is not as user-friendly as I'd like, because I then have to pre-brief the user as to whether any input they've typed on that prompt prior to (or after) issuing the `SIGINT` will be saved or not. (Intuitively you might expect it not to be, but I don't want to take that for granted among my users.)

Is there any way I can have the signal-handler fire immediately on Ctrl+C and break out of the prompt?

Comment: there are a few asynchonous php libraries out there such as 'AsyncPhpSocket ' that you may like to give a look at.
Your may like to check out `fopen('php://stdin', 'r')` and read that in a `while(true)` loop

Comment: I was wondering if some form of async method would provide an answer, but I've no experience with that and wouldn't really know where to start by myself. Also I fear that the process/thread in which `readline()` was executing might still be immune to signals. As for a while(true) loop, without some method of pausing execution won't that just be a CPU-bomb?